# Files on web server can be found without extensions

Tags: server, php, .htaccess

I have a page `about.php`. I can access this page by either `example.com/about.php` or `example.com/about` and even `example.com/about/`. The latter does something strange. It treats the `about.php` (which is in `public_html`) as if it is `index.php` inside an `about` folder. I know this because when I open it that way the images don't display (as if the images are in an upper folder)

I do have to set up some rules for `htaccess` but it is no the `htaccess` file because there isn't one yet.

What else can be causing this?

Comment: Are you sure there is no `.htaccess` file? Remember that files beginning with a dot '.' are not visible by default. If you are using a terminal, `ls -a` will display hidden files. If you are using Nautilus, pressing Ctrl+H will display hidden files (IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [content-negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html) is active. See the comment on the linked page regaring the directory effect.